# Server.Transfer to an HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have an IHttpHandler with the following ProcessRequest method:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"] + 151);
    var xml = XDocument.Parse("<xml><cartid>" + id + "</cartid></xml>");
    context.Response.Write(xml);
}
```

Which I'm trying to use from an aspx page as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    order o = new order();
    Server.Transfer(o, false);
}
```

I get an HttpException: Error executing child request for handler 'PostTest.order'.

If I instead try doing the transfer like:

```
Server.Transfer("~/order.ashx?id=65", false)
```

I get an HttpException: Error executing child request for /order.ashx.

Am I doing this wrong or is there another way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Anything wrong with using Response.Redirect()?

Comment: The aspx page is recieving a POST with data from another server (not a user's browser) and I'm not sure it's going to do the redirect, but I'll try.

Comment: Why not just have your other server call the handler directly, and move the necessary logic from your ASPX page to there? An ASPX page isn't really going to make a good endpoint for another server to call.

Comment: It's not our server and the other company's people are less than helpful, so I was trying to work around that.  I'll probably end up asking them to change their link, but thought someone might know a quick solution.

Comment: Could stick the logic in the ASPX page, call Response.Clear() from your Page_Load method, and directly handle the call from there using the same logic as you have in your handler. Ugly, but should work in a pinch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just pass the context:

```
var handler = new order();
handler.ProcessRequest(Context);
Response.End();
```

Comment: That's really cool. I've been using ASP.NET for YEARS and didn't know this.

Comment: using the above code can i pass something in the request and get back response from the handler

Comment: That's good, unless you want to access the query string from the handler (the query string will be the one of the current page, unlike what you'd get with Server.Transfer). I guess no choice...