# HttpContext not available in Class Library

Tags: c#, httpcontext, system.web

I am working on a project where I have a C# class library which needs to use the `System.web.HttpContext`. I've done this before in another project without problem but now its not working. I'm not sure what I am missing they're both targeting .net 3.5 and I've added the reference `System.web` and added the directive `using System.web`.

However, when I try and do `HttpContext` nothing is found. I've tried using the full path `System.web.HttpContext` but the only thing that comes up are 3 items related to ASP.

Below are screenshots from the working project intellisense and the non-working intellisense

Below is the working screenshot

[image: working screenshot]

and below is the non working screenshot

[image: not working screenshot]

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Did you add a reference to the System.Web .Net assembly in your project?

Comment: @saarp I did say in the question that I added the reference and the directive

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This means that either you are using a Client Profile as the Target Framework or the reference to System.Web was not added correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I had it has a client profile by mistake, thought I'd changed it to the full version.

Comment: Just to note "Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the Client Profile is no longer available. The full re-distributable has been optimized for faster deployment and smaller disk space. You no longer have to decide whether to use the Client Profile or the full .NET Framework—just target the .NET Framework 4.5."  [.NET Framework Client Profile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc656912(v=vs.100).aspx), August 2012

Answer (score 7):

Despite your comment that you've added reference to System.Web to the project it is still most likely reason of what you are seeing.

The classes you see are coming from System.Dll, not System.Web.Dll.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add some input incase someone else gets hung up on this. If you are in a Unit test project or a Class Library that links back to an MVC project, you may have references to **System.Web.Mvc**. This DOES NOT INCLUDE **System.Web**. You must add both if you need something Mvc specific (like a SelectList) AND HttpContext