# Request.QueryString not recognized, System.Web included in namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, query-string, system.web

A simple question but I'd rather ask since I had problem with it two times.

I am trying to retrieve hostname from the url in ASP.NET project. The code is actually not in a web page but in a class (part of the domain). System.Web is included in the headers. When I try to use Request.QueryString it is not recognized. Even worse if I try HttpContext.Current, I get this error

```
'System.Web.HttpContext.Current' is null
```

Here is my code

```
using System.Web;

public class MyNightlyJob : AbstractJob
{
    public override void ExecuteJob(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
          HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]; // does not work
          Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]; // this does not work also
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Note that my question is actually about Request.ServerVariables but if one works, the other will work too.

Note that Request.ServerVariable is not recognized in the code at all. HttpContext.Current is recognized but I get run time error for that.

Comment: Where are you calling this method from?  Is it executing on the same thread as the HTTP request?

Comment: Not sure about the thread at all. I have 4 application in one Solution, if that helps. It is web application, not a threaded application AFAIK.

Comment: try HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["HTTP_HOST"]

Comment: Maybe you can post the code that calls this method?  It sounds like you're not using it in the right scope.

Comment: I can step through it. ExecuteJob is automatically called I guess. It is part of Quartz.NET.

Comment: How do I know which thread it is executed in? Is there any way to debug?

Comment: see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149815/httpcontext-not-available-in-class-library helps?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if HttpContext.Current is a null. If it is null then its not in the right context to be retrieved.

If you can modify the function, I would pass the HttpContext.Current as a variable or pass the host as a variable.

Comment: That's a good idea but it is a big code and I myself does not want to make this change. Yes, `HttpContext.Current` is returned null in my code.