# How to bind generic handler to Label.Text in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, generic-handler

I am trying to bind output of generic handler to Label. Make it simple. My handler only write the "Hello World" string.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }
```

And I want to bind this to some label in aspx page. I am trying this code, but it doesnt work.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("../Handler1.ashx");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (response)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            reader.ReadToEnd();
            Label1.Text = reader.ReadLine();

        }
```

It raises error bad Uri. Thanks for your ideas and comments. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to this - [How to call HttpHandler from .cs file asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535754/how-to-call-httphandler-from-cs-file-asp-net)

You need to provide an absolute URI. Also note that the `ReadToEnd()` call will do precisely that; subsequently calling `ReadLine` will return an empty string.

```
    HttpWebRequest  request  = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:11034/handlers/handler1.ashx");
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    using (response)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        Label1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```